# Problem with React-Toolkit, Types and Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, toolkit, redux-toolkit

I was following this tutorial to understand how to use redux-toolkit in a React project.
https://redux-flash-cards.netlify.com/
I was able to compile and execute the project successfully.

Due to restrictions in my current project, I am not able to use Typescript for this React project, so I am trying to use the same project only with javascript. 
So, I started to rewrite some of the code in the Javascript way. However, there are some incompatibilities that I do not know how to solve.

My problem is that I'm geeting an error

```
'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file
```

in the line (16) of flash-cards/src/redux/store.ts.

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

I think that it is becasue Javascript cannot use types.

The above problem is causing other errors on lines 25, 30 and 31 of flash-cards/src/App.tsx, because this file cannot import the previous file (in JS version). So I don't know how to do (line 25)

```
import { RootState } from "./redux/store"
```

Somebody was suggesting me to use flow or proptypes to solve the problem, but really I got lost finding the correct solution.

I will appreciate a lot if you can give a hand to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using an incorrect path and double store.